# How does ms word vba detect the end of a paragraph

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I converted an html text into a docx document using several different online converters.

Then I analysed the number of paragraphs using an Excel vba macro which opens the document and examines it. Supplied with an original docx document (ie one not converted from another format) this macro always gives the correct number of paragraphs.

Only one converter yielded a docx from which the number of paragraphs could be determined. All the others simply said there was a single paragraph with hundreds of words in it.

Somehow the html to docx converters are missing something. What is missing ? Can I dob it in ?

Comment: What does the converted html look like when you hit the show/hide paragraph marks?

Comment: I can't find what you ask for. I looked along the ribbon to "Page Layout" and then "Paragraphs". Then I expanded "spacing" using the arrow in the BRHC. But I can't see any paragraph marks. I looked back to a document .docx where the macro worked and the data seems very similar. The computer in use for this job is not connected to the internet, has XP-Pro as the operating system and uses MS Office 2003

Comment: Office 2003 running on XP?! O boy, that takes me back!

Answer (score 0):

Tools / Options / View.

[image: Display non-printing characters]

Examine the characters that Word uses to delimit paragraphs in the docx and the translated html.

[image: like ths]

I suspect that "paragraphs" in the translated html might be manual line breaks. If so, that would account for the fact that the paragraph count in the translated html is incorrect.

Comment: Eventually I found this. You are quite right. The converrter has put line breaks. Closed and thank you.  David

Comment: I'm happy to help. Feel free to click the "Accept Answer" button.